# Finding length and width of regular/irregular polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, measurements

How can I find the length and width of regular and irregular polygons on QGIS? There's > 1000 so can't measure manually with the line tool.

I have perimeter and area but need the other two measurements too.

Comment: Measured how? Can you add a screenshot

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Field calculator to find the with and length of the equivalent rectangle solving quadratic equation:

```
Perimeter = 2 (a + b)
Area = a * b  => a = Area / b
Substitute a into the first equation
Perimeter = 2 Area / b + 2 b

2 b^2 - Perimeter b + 2 Area = 0 the two roots are the width and length
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try Minimum bounding geometry:

[image]

Height and width attributes in output. You can join them back to the original data using id column.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'Layer_B'* (green), see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to find the length and width of regular and irregular polygons.

```sql
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.info,
    Envelope(b.geometry) AS geom,
    round(st_area(Envelope(b.geometry)), 2) AS area,
    round(st_perimeter(Envelope(b.geometry)), 2) AS perimeter,
    round(st_maxx(Envelope(b.geometry)) - st_minx(Envelope(b.geometry)),2) AS length,
    round(st_maxy(Envelope(b.geometry)) - st_miny(Envelope(b.geometry)),2) AS width
FROM
    "Layer_B" AS b
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [PostGIS Docs | ST_Envelope()](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html)